# How to fix parsing int from string?

Tags: c#, parseint

I am trying to get the percent at the end of a string (i.e. "50013 / 247050 [20%]" I would want the 20 at the end.) for some reason it keeps returning -1. What is the problem with my code?

```
public int percent(String s)
{
    String outp = "-1";

    if(s != null)
    outp = s;

    try
    {
        outp = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("["), s.IndexOf("%"));
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
    }

    int outt = int.Parse(outp);
    return outt;
}
```

Comment: Empty catch is a bad habit to kick.

Comment: in addition to Tim Schmelter, exceptions should be exceptions. You can check the index on -1 value with **if** statements without the use of exceptions, much better practice.

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter isn't a *index* but a *count*. So you should do something like this:

```
// because, you don't want the [, you'll add 1 to the index,
int index1 = s.IndexOf("[") + 1;
int index2 = s.IndexOf("%");
string outp = s.Substring(index1, index2 - index1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regex for this

```
string text = "50013 / 247050 [20%]";
var outp = Regex.Match(text, @"\[(\d+)%\]").Groups[1].Value;
```